# Facebook apprequests dialog custom message/title - bug or just bad docs

Tags: facebook

[This is a link to their docs page for apprequests dialog.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/)

This is what they show as an integration example:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'My Great Request'
}, requestCallback);
```

Yet further down the page they show a list of parameters which can be used, **message** is not listed but **title** is.

But using title fails, causing no friends data to be loaded:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
    title: 'My Great Request'
}, requestCallback);
```

So, Is there a way to have a custom message in the app requests?